# Function that checks if a variable is of type that is passed as parameter in swift

Tags: swift

I'd like to write a function that will either `doSomething()` or `doSomethingElse()` depending on whether a passed parameter `a` is of type `B`. Where `B` is passed as a second parameter to that function.

My attempt:

```
func magic<T>(a: Any, b: T.Type) {
    if a is b {
        doSomething()
    } else {
        doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Ah. Seems like I can check for a is T. But then I don't use the parameter b...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
func magic<T>(a: Any, b: T.Type) {
    if a is T {
        doSomething()
    } else {
        doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

But maybe generic is not what you need here. You can have multiple overloads instead:

```
func magic(someType: SomeType) {
    // do Something
}

func magic(someOtherType: SomeOtherType) {
    // do Something else
}
```

This way you can be sure about the type at the compile time instead of run-time.

Comment: Great suggestion using overloads instead! For the version using generics, it feels weird to "not use b". Is there a way around that?

Comment: Yes there is. I've posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77436416/5623035) for those insists on using `b` parameter for type check at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

How to check the types using the `b` parameter explicitly:

```
func magic<T>(a: Any, b: T.Type) {
    if type(of: a) == b.self {
        doSomething()
    } else {
        doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

This will be used like:

```
magic(a: 12, b: Int.self)
```

---

Note that it will be `not equal` for subclasses and protocol conformances.

For example although `Text` conforms to the `View`, the function performs `doSomethingElse` if you call this:

```
magic(a: Text(""), b: (any View).self)
```

This is true for the Inheritance too:

```
class Human { }
class Student: Human { }

magic(a: Student(), b: Human.self) // Performs `doSomethingElse`
```